# How to set up environments in Pycharm when working with two machines?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I work with my laptop and work PC. I save my python files/codes in a Onedrive folder. I use Pycharm to run my python files. The problem is: My work PC cannot run a file that runs successfully in my laptop. It returns the following error message. How can I set up Pycharm or the environment so that the file can work with both machines?

```
9:17 PM Error running 'Morningstar_requests_creation': Cannot run program "C:\Users\duckman\Anaconda3\python.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\123456\OneDrive\PyCharm"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Same OS on both machines?

Comment: Yes, both window

Comment: Possible solution is to created interpreters with the same name on both machines. The interpreter name is saved inside project, it will be synced through onedrive, PyCharm instance on another machine will load this name and choose the appropriate interpreter, and your issue will run away.